# Android internal storage and package

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app and I'm using internal storage to save some data into a file but I can't find it on the device. I made a toast that says that the file was saved on data/data/com.example.example/files but for some reason when I try to find this location, with a file explorer, there's nothing there. I know the file exists because when I read try to read from it everything that I wrote is there. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's a permission issue. By default, file saved in internal storage is only accessible by the app which saved it. As a result, whenever you try to read it from your application the file is there but when another application like a file explorer tries to read it android blocks its access. So the file remains invisible. To know more about that click [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)